# dynamically add alternate text for your Image using the image URL is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this problem that I need to change the Alternate text based on the Image source. For example I have a folder marked images which contains all of the images used for the project.

```
<table id="OptionPics">
    <tr><td><img id="OptionPic1" alt="" src="images/selection1.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img id="OptionPic2" alt="" src="images/selection2.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img id="OptionPic3" alt="" src="images/selection3.png" /></td></tr>
</table>
<table id="SelectedPicTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="SelectedPic" alt="" src="images/placeholder.png" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want to know is if it's possible to change the **SelectedPic**'s alt according to which image was clicked? 
For example, if **OptionPic1** is clicked the **SelectedPic**'s alt should be **"selection1"** instead of **images/selection1.png**".

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. Are you doing this so that your page validates? because, by the time the javascript runs, the validation has usually already occurred.

Comment: You are not supposed to have two elements with the same id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you control the click in the images? It's pure javascript or you are using jQuery?

today it's very common to use jQuery, than, I will assume that you are using it:

```
<table id="OptionPics">
<tr><td><img id="OptionPic1" class="options" alt="" src="images/selection1.png" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="OptionPic2" class="options" alt="" src="images/selection2.png" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img id="OptionPic3" class="options" alt="" src="images/selection3.png" /></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="SelectedPic">
<tr><td><img id="SelectedPic" alt="" src="images/placeholder.png" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

look that I inserted a class, named **options** to all the images.
now let's write our jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.options').on('click', function(){ //everytime a image is clicked
        var i = $(this); //handle to the clicked image
        $('img#SelectedPic').attr('src', i.attr('src')).attr('alt', i.attr('alt'));
        //insert into image with the SelectedPic ID, the same src and alt attributes of the clicked image
    });
});
```

Comment: or: `$('#OptionPics').on('click', "img", function()`

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't in the mood for jQuery, here it is in pure JS:

http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/6YUhg/

HTML:

```
<table id="OptionPics">
<tr><td><img class="OptionPic1 optPics" alt="" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png?image=1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img class="OptionPic2 optPics" alt="" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png?image=2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><img class="OptionPic3 optPics" alt="" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png?image=3" /></td></tr>
</table>

<table id="SelectedPicTable">
<tr><td><img id="SelectedPic" alt="" src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("optPics");
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
{
    (function(image){
        image.onclick=function(){
            var imageParts = image.src.split('/');
            var imageName = imageParts[imageParts.length-1];
            document.getElementById("SelectedPic").alt=imageName;
            document.getElementById("SelectedPic").title=imageName;
        }
    }(imgs[i]))
}
```

A couple quick notes on the above code: Note that I also change the title attribute - changing the alt has no effect in some versions FireFox, and it seems likely others might also ignore changes to the alt attribute. Changing the 'title' attribute gives the hover text change. I included both for reference.

Also, I am stripping out the image path as you requested, but if for some reason your images will have '/' characters after the filename you will need to modify this code. In my example I distinguish the images with a querystring, so I don't strip the extension, but if you want to have just the filename, change the appropriate line to `var imageName = imageParts[imageParts.length-1].split('.')[0];`

Comment: And because I can't let sleeping dogs lie here is a version that should work fairly universally http://jsfiddle.net/MaxPRafferty/Y4Ff3/